# How to have a origin repository in local workstation

Tags: git, filesystems

for work, I have a Java project in a repo GIT, stored only in the local workstation and there's not any remote repo.

Because of some reasons, I can't create a remote repo, then I'm asking myself if I can create a *"master"* repo in my local machine.

In details te situation is:

- I have already a local repo of my project in **C:\ProjectWorkspace.git** (call this A)
- the original remote repo is not more reachable
- Then, I can't run

  > git pull
  >
  > git push

To solve the problem;

- I want to copy the actual repo (maybe, it's more correct to run 'git init') in a new directory **B** different from **A** in the same workstation
- point the *'master/origin'* of my repo in **A** to this new repo in **B**

But, how I can let communicate the two repo?

In general we use the *http*, *https* or *ssh* protocols to link local and remote repos, because of the presence of a client/server architecture.

But in local, by filesystem?

Is it possible to use the *file* protocol? The workstation runs in *Windows 7*, I can't install *cyngwin* or similar.

If it's possibile, what are the steps?

Overall, what's the equivalent instruction of

```
> git remote add origin git@github.com:username/new_repo
```

?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed push to and pull from a repository on the local system.  Git itself uses this extensively in its testsuite.  You can specify either a local path or a file URL.  If you use a file URL, the path must be absolute.

So you could write one of these (for a Windows system):

```
$ git remote add origin C:/remotes/project.git
$ git remote add origin file:///C%3a/remotes/project.git
```

You could also use a relative path if you use the former syntax.  Then, you can simply push as normal:

```
$ git push origin master
```

If you already have an `origin` remote and wish to replace it, use `git remote set-url` instead of `git remote add`.

When you do this, Git spawns a `git-receive-pack` process in the remote repository as a normal server would do, and runs the protocol much like it would do in a push over SSH.